# Strange 2 dimensional list behaviour in python

Tags: python, list

Why does python do the following?

```
>>> bla = [[]] * 5
>>> bla[3].append("blub")
>>> print bla
[['blub'], ['blub'], ['blub'], ['blub'], ['blub']]
```

I would expect

```
[[], [], [], ['blub'], []]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common point of confusion with Python, to do with the implicit pass-by-reference. When you type

```
x = []
```

that binds the name `x` to point to an empty list in memory. When you do

```
x = [[]] * 5
```

that binds the name `x` to point to a list of five things, each one of which is a reference to the *same* empty list. This might be clearer if you think of it like this:

```
>>> y = []
>>> x = [y]*5
>>> x
[[], [], [], [], []]
>>> x[0].append(0)
>>> x
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
>>> y
[0]
```

That is, even though `[]` doesn't bind any variable names, it still creates a reference to an empty list, which is then copied five times.

If you don't want this, you need explicitly to construct *five* empty lists to store in `x`. There are various ways of doing this (`copy.deepcopy` is a general solution), but I think the neatest is:

```
x = [[] for _ in range(5)]
```

Alternatively, `numpy` is an extension module which provides a very powerful multidimensional array.

Answer (score 4):

You're multiplying the contents of the original list five times - that inner list is just a reference, so the same reference is multiplied five times.

In other words, the final list you've got is a list containing the same list multiple times.

An easy way around this for Python 2:

```
[[] for i in xrange(5)]
```

Python 3:

```
[[] for i in range(5)]
```

Comment: `_` (over `i`) is recommended because it indicates "I'm not actually using this" (while `i` is often used as index).